# show frame created by opencv in graphicsView made by pyqt4

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt4, qt-designer

I write code by python and openCV to create frame. I want view this frame in graphicsView  object  that I created by QT designer. and frame ***fill*** graphicsView  object

my code to create frame :

```
 webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        while(webcam.isOpened()):
            ret, frame = webcam.read()

            if ret:
                 gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                 faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
                 for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
                     cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
                     face = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
                     face_resize = cv2.resize(face, (width, height))
                     #Try to recognize the face
                     prediction = model.predict(face_resize)
                     cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
                     if prediction[1]<500:
                          cv2.putText(frame,'%s - %.0f' % (names[prediction[0]],prediction[1]),(x-10, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1,(0, 255, 0))
                          if names[prediction[0]]==str(self.comboBox.currentText()):
                               x_left = x-width
                               x_right = width - w - x
                               print "left={0}\nright={1}".format(x_left, x_right)
                     else:
                          cv2.putText(frame,'not recognized',(x-10, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1,(0, 255, 0))
                # cv2.imshow('OpenCV', frame)
                 self.MainWindow.graphicsView.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(frame))
                 key = cv2.waitKey(10)
                 if key == 27:
                      break
```

the code generate by qt is:

```
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(1300, 800)
        MainWindow.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(990, 570, 75, 23))
        self.graphicsView = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(5, 1, 911, 761))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("graphicsView"))
```

Comment: Is it feasible to provide enough code to be a working program?